# Invalid length for Convert.FromBase64String

Tags: c#, string, encryption, cryptography

So I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted string, it encrypts fine, and sometimes decrypts it if I'm lucky enough but usually the string length is too long.. firstly here is the code where I called the decryption method

```
decrypted = Decrypt(recieved, getString(anarchyAes.Key));
addToChat(decrypted);
```

recieved is just the encrypted string, and the other parameter is the decryption key. Here is the Decrypt method..

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, string securityKey)
    {
        var key = securityKey;
        var keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            Key = keyArray,
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        };

        var cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        var toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);
        var resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }
```

It fails when it does

```
var toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);
```

When the string is more than 7 characters giving the error, invalid length for a 64 base string. I'm wondering how I could possibly fix this, any insight is appreciated.

Encrpytion code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string securityKey)
        {
            var key = securityKey;
            var keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

            var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = keyArray,
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            };

            var cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            var toEncryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
            var resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }
```

Comment: TripleDES is not very secure, and ECB is very insecure.

Comment: How is your string generated?

Comment: I'll add the encryption code 1 sec

Comment: Have you verified the output base64 string from `Encrypt` is identical to the one received by `Decrypt`? If your using HTTP some base64 characters can cause problems.

Comment: The string are just messages. If I type something like "yo" it works perfectly but for mostly anything longer than that it will fail.

Comment: Your example appears to call `FromBase64String` on a value generated by `ToBase64String` - this should always work.  Log the return value of `Encrypt` and log what gets passed to `Decrypt`

Comment: For example if I type "yo" it encrypts it to Z52tk7jooxU=

Comment: I am using a server though so the encypted string is sent to the server, and sent back to another client

Comment: And what is generated for a value that causes the error?

Comment: An error would be if I typed "you suck" in chat it would encrypt it to "wirWtYc59Hhq00Dtmpga g=="

Comment: Ahhh it seems like any encrypted string that contains a space will fail. If I type "stuff" it converts it to an ecrypted string that has a space in it, while "stoof" converts to a string with no space and works fine.

Comment: `ToBase64String` will never output a space, but it can output a `+` which can be url decoded in some cases *to* a space.  So if you *are* using HTTP make sure you urlencode the Base64

Comment: @AlexK. That's one approach, but personally I prefer using the `base64url` encoding without padding specified in [RFC-4648](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7). It uses `-` and `_` as the two special characters which don't need any special treatment in urls.